# Dynamically update lit CSS module based on attribute

Tags: javascript, css, attributes, web-component, lit-element

I have a component that I want to style/theme based on an attribute. Depending on the attribute value, I want to import a different stylesheet/css module.

Ideally it would be something along the lines of

```
import module1 from 'css-module1.js'
import module2 from 'css-module2.js'

@customElement('component')
export class Component extends LitElement {
  static styles = attribute ? [module1] : [module2]

  @property({reflect: true})
  attribute = <value>

  <rest of file>
}
```

Everything I see suggests that dynamic attribute based css only works for

```
static styles = css`
  :host([attribute]) { <css> }
`
```

Is it possible to dynamically assign the style based on an attribute? The stylesheet is too large to realistically put multiple attribute based copies within the file itself.

Answer (score 1):

This question may be solved by using a technique from [lit.dev styles documentation](https://lit.dev/docs/components/styles/#style-element).

Your example presented results in the styles being evaluated **once per class**. Which is a high performance solution. However your described case requires styles to be changed based on an attribute, which can be different **per instance** of the component.

Therefore the following options are available:

#### Include a `<style>` element in the Lit template

```
render() {
  return html`
    <style>
      :host {
        /* Warning: this approach has limitations & performance issues! */
        color: ${myColor}
      }
    </style>
    <div>template content</div>
  `;
}
```

Note: Evaluating an expression inside a  element is inefficient. When any text inside a  element changes, the browser must re-parse the whole  element, resulting in unnecessary work.

Performance cost can be mitigated by only applying the styles that change in the `<style>` element. E.g.:

```
 // Static styles that do not change between cases.
 static styles = css`/* ... */`;

 
  render() {
    const module1 = html`<style> :host { color: red; } </style>`;
    return html`${this.attribute ? module1 : module2}`
```

#### Use `styleMap` or `classMap`

Another way to make styles dynamic is to add expressions to the `class` or `style` attributes in your template, and `classMap` and `styleMap` can be used to easily apply classes or styles based on conditions, such as your `this.attribute` value.

Read more about them: https://lit.dev/docs/components/styles/#dynamic-classes-and-styles

This may require changing what you're importing from `css-module.js`.